# Login my user by openid

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, security, openid

I'm going to have a *web site* where the user can take data from a *webservice* but I want that **only logged user can insert data through the webservice into my db**.

The login process is based on openID and the system is in php.

How can I check on webservice that the user in **correct logged in**?

Comment: With some source code, that would be a good place to start which you don't seem to have here so nothing to fix. No solid answer can be give, this is asking for a tutorial which isn't suitable for stackoverflow.

Comment: @NewToJS I need a "how to" place where start. I read something about implementing an openid session but, the question is, how make the webservice able to understand that my user is logged in

Comment: So you are looking for a tutorial/guide, not for help with a specific piece of source code.

Comment: @NewToJS yes, I do

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a tutorials website. It's for those with a specific problem with existing source code. Please take the time to read [**How To Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @NewToJS ok but let's do this, it is not a how to that I looking for but it is a: I've got the token from my openID provider which library can I use in php to check if the token is valid?

Comment: Maybe the answers to this question might be of some help to you. [**What is call to function $openid->validate do?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698784/what-is-call-to-function-openid-validate-do)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157730/discussion-between-salvatore-di-fazio-and-newtojs).